# TypeError 'cb is not a function' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a function prepare

```
const prepare = (store, component) => (
    (nextState, cb) => {
        const { dispatch, getState } = store;
        const state = getState();
        const pageState = getPageState(state);
        const { init, dirty } = pageState;
        const { app: { branch } } = state;

        // doing some stuff
       

        return cb(null, component);
    }
);
```

using it as below

```
prepare(store, component)
```

expecting the function to return just the component

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `return` site and watch what `cb` is actually.

Comment: It is returning an empty object

Comment: `prepare(store, component)` - What is `component` here? Can you edit to include a more complete [mcve]? Is this related to your existing question [here](/q/74369738/8690857)?

Comment: @DrewReese - component is just a UI component.  Anyhow got the issue resolved by modifying 'prepare' function. cb wasn't required ideally, returned just the component.